# yii2 Fullcalendar - Why is alert for CalEvent working but not for updating innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, yii2, fullcalendar

I am using `philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar` and I want to show the event description.

when I am using the code:

```
<script>
var JSEventClick = (function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
   //  document.getElementsByClassName('.fc-title').innerHtml += 'calEvent.nonstandard.field1' ;
    alert(calEvent.title + ' -- ' + calEvent.nonstandard.field1);
});
</script>
```

it is working fine.

but when I am using:

```
<script>
var JSEventClick = (function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
     document.getElementsByClassName('.fc-title').innerHtml += calEvent.nonstandard.field1 ;
  //  alert(calEvent.title + ' -- ' + calEvent.nonstandard.field1);
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
(function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
     document.getElementsByClassName('.fc-title').innerHtml += calEvent.nonstandard.field1;
  //  alert(calEvent.title + ' -- ' + calEvent.nonstandard.field1);
});
</script>
```

also tried

```
<script>
var JSEventClick = (function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var myEvent = document.getElementsByClassName('.fc-title') ;
    var codeBlock = ( ' -- ' + calEvent.nonstandard.field1);
    myEvent.innerHtml += codeBlock;
  //  alert(calEvent.title + ' -- ' + calEvent.nonstandard.field1);
});
</script>
```

The contents of my html:

IPS Annual Day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line where you have the problem

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.fc-title').innerHtml += calEvent.nonstandard.field1;
```

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return an array-like object with all the tags which have the class you have specified. An array-like object doesn't have an `innerHTML`. The tags stored in the array-like object have an `innerHTML`. Also, I believe that you do not have an .fc-title class, you have an fc-title class instead, finally, make sure that `innerHTML` is typed properly. Proposed solution:

```
for (var element of document.getElementsByClassName('fc-title')) {
    element.innerHTML += calEvent.nonstandard.field1
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Lajos Arpad. That worked nice. can you also help me to show the same(`calEvent.nonstandard.field1`) as pop-up on mouseOver. my `eventMouseover` is working ok, but I want that to be as a pop-up. or alternatively the same included without click.

Comment: @Joshi gladly. Please create another question for that purpose and add a link to that here in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks. I have created the question. link is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050155/yii2-fullcalendar-add-a-popup-to-element