# yii2 fullcalendar add a popup to element

Tags: javascript, yii2, fullcalendar

I was able to add the event description using the code

```
<script>
var JSEventClick = (function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    for (var element of document.getElementsByClassName('fc-title')) {
    element.innerHTML += calEvent.nonstandard.field1
}
});
</script>
```

using the help from answer from this link - [yii2 Fullcalendar - Why is alert for CalEvent working but not for updating innerHtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048115/yii2-fullcalendar-why-is-alert-for-calevent-working-but-not-for-updating-inner)

Now I am trying to add the same as popup on mouseover event.

```
<?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
      'events'=> $events,
      'id'=>'calendar',

       'clientOptions' => [ 
        'editable' => true,
        'eventSources' => ['/eventcalendar/index'],
        'draggable' => true,
        'droppable' => true,
        'eventClick' => new JsExpression('JSEventClick'),
        ],

  ));?>
```

This is working fine.

and the related html looks like this:

```
<td class="fc-event-container">
<a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable">
<div class="fc-content"> 
<span class="fc-title">IPS Annual Day</span></div>
<div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div></a></td>
```

How I can achieve this that is the info in `calEvent.nonstandard.field1` show as popup on mouseover.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgable with yii, but, as promised, I have looked into it. I wonder whether this property inside clientOptions 'eventMouseover'=>new CJavaScriptExpression("js_function_callback"), would help. Inspired from: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/efullcalendar

Comment: yes @LajosArpad - only thing what you mentioned is `CJavaScriptExpression` which is for yii and I am using yii2 - where I am using `eventClick' => new JsExpression('JSEventClick'),` and this can be used as `eventMouseOver` =>new JsExpression('JSEventClick'),` `

Comment: so while using alert with `eventMouseOver` I was getting the alert correctly.

Comment: That's a very good point. So, if I understand you correctly, it works for you if you use eventMouseOver => new JsExpression("JSEventClick"). Am I right in stating this, or is there still a problem to solve?

Comment: No @LajosArpad - what I stated is that the `eventMouseOver` is working when I do an alert, but not for add html. but thanks for your time. I found the solution and posting the same here as well.

Comment: Joshi, I see, the solution was to assign it to the attribute called content.

Comment: yes @LajosArpad you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution which is working for me and hope other will find it useful.

```
 <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
    'events' => $events,
    'eventRender' => new JsExpression(
    <<<'JS'
    (eventObj, $el)=>{
        $el.popover({
        title: eventObj.title,
            content: eventObj.nonstandard.field1,
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'top',
            container: 'body'
    });
    }
JS
            )
        ]);

?>
  </div>
```

here field1 is the non standard field passed in events array in controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are several [event handlers](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-clicking-hovering) in full calendar plugin:

- eventClick
- eventMouseEnter
- eventMouseLeave

So you can try

```
<?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
  'events'=> $events,
  'id'=>'calendar',

   'clientOptions' => [ 
    'editable' => true,
    'eventSources' => ['/eventcalendar/index'],
    'draggable' => true,
    'droppable' => true,
    'eventMouseEnter' => new JsExpression('JSEventClick'),
    ],
```

));?>